# Error with linking flag when using the cmake build for cppyy

Tags: c++, cmake, cppyy

I am trying to build the example for a make build for cppyy in the `cppyy-knearestneighbors` example (https://github.com/jclay/cppyy-knearestneighbors-example). From what I understand it used the more modern cppyy cmake.

However when it comes to the linking I find this error,

```
ld: unknown option: --no-as-needed
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [knn_example/libknn_exampleCppyy.dylib] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/knn_exampleCppyy.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I couldn't find away to remove this flag as it seems to be something internal to cppyy cmake. Is there any work around to fix the compilation?

Comment: Are you using ninja or make?

Comment: I have tried with both, same error

Answer (score 0):

I cannot talk about `cppyy` since I have never used it, but since it internally uses CMake, the issue that you have could control by the value of the LINK_WHAT_YOU_USE property.

I would first try to disable the default value of LINK_WHAT_YOU_USE with:

```
# When running cmake configure:
cmake -GNinja -DCMAKE_LINK_WHAT_YOU_USE=OFF
```

If it does not work, a more evolve approach which means iterating all of the targets and unsetting their LINK_WHAT_YOU_USE property. Let me know if you need help for this

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LINK_WHAT_YOU_USE.html#variable:CMAKE_LINK_WHAT_YOU_USE